# Dynamically loading Javascript in Head Tag one by one after completely loaded not appending, Cross Domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, cross-browser, signalr

1. Here I am appending jQuery fist afterwards my Custom java-script file
2. Problem is before jQuery is loaded completely my Custom java-script file try to execute, then I get error.
3. This problem appear only on first time load from next time on wards it wont appear, because jquery content will load from cache and my custom js will load from browser.

   ```
   function AppendJavascriptIframes(iframeDocumnet, url)   
   {  
       var js;  
       var headTag = iframeDocumnet.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];  
       js = iframeDocumnet.createElement('script');  
       js.src = url;  
       headTag.appendChild(js);  
   }

   AppendJavascriptIframes(myIframe.contentWindow.document, "js/jquery-1.8.2.js");  
   AppendJavascriptIframes(myIframe.contentWindow.document, "js/MyCustomScript.js");
   ```
4. To over come this presently I am using following code

   ```
   setTimeout(function () { AppendJavascriptIframes(myIframe.contentWindow.document, "js/MyCustomScript.js"); }, 1600);
   ```
5. But this will load after this 1600 much of Mili sec, but I don't what to given this much of time dealay it approx 2 sec. He may leave the page with 2 sec

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function loadjsfile(filename, filetype){

  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}
```

Comment: if it is undefined it wont load right ? according to you condition. But i want to load java-script file

Comment: yes but the element will not be undefined as we are creating it explicitly. if condition is added to ensure that if any how fileref is undefined don't append the js

Comment: Here i am not asking is java-script file is added or not. My Question after loading is completed of fist refereed java-script how that i will came know ??